# How to use tSystem on Talend on Mac

Tags: macos, command-line, talend

hope you're all fine,

I just switched from windows to mac
and I imported my talend project.

In one job, I have to unzip an archive, using 7z.
All fine, but can't find how to do this using tSystem on Mac.
For windows I did something like /cmd /c etc ...
But can't find on the internet how to do so with osx

Maybe someone knows ?

Thanks a lot

Ivan

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same component tsystem

You simply need to change the command inside. From windows command to unix command.

Comment: Hit thanks, my conmand is 7z -e file.7z but didn't work. Is it the right one on OS X ?

Comment: Maybe ty another zip program like : https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-compress-and-uncompress-files-and-folders-in-os-x-lion-10-7-using-terminal/